# How to get the data from Google Analytics API up to sepcific hour

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'd like to get the data from Google Analytics with filter: hour below 15.

I've tried both the API and Query explorer and I'm getting some errors each time.

Below is my query:

[image: Screen shot from the query explorer]

Is there a way to make that work, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ga:hour` is a dimension not a metric so it is a string (not a number).

You can use regex like this:

```
ga:hour=~(00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14)
```

The regex can be optimized however the concept is the one described.